# How to do Neighborhood Summary Statistics by Year in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, geotools, time-series, nearest-neighbor

I am attempting to calculate neighborhood summary statistics for groups of administrative polygons for each year between 2002 and 2018 in ArcGIS Pro. In ArcGIS Pro the Neighborhood Summary Statistics tool does not seem to allow me to index by Year. Does anyone have any advice for how best to do this?